# Angular 5 - Capture the entire Form including UL, LI

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a new to Angular 2+ so please pardon me if this question seems silly.

I have a simple HTML template which has a `form` element 2 input boxes and dropdown list.

**VIEW**

```
<form class = 'form-class'
      [formGroup] = form
      (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(form.value)"
>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'firstName' placeholder="Enter First Name ..." formControlName="firstName">
  <input type = 'text' name = 'lastName' placeholder="Enter Last Name ..." formControlName="lastName">
  <span>{{ selectedLang }}</span>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let lang of languagesList" (click)="selectedLang = lang" > {{ lang }} </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
export class ModelDrivenFormsComponent implements OnInit {
  form;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      selectedLang: new FormControl(this.selectedLang) // this doesn't work
    });
  }
  languagesList = ['English', 'Hindi', 'Konkani'];
  selectedLang = 'Select Now';

  onSubmit = function (user) {
    user.selectedLang = this.selectedLang; // <-- this is something i want to avoid
  }

}
```

The Above is the **model driven form**. Similarly I have also tried using **template driven form** in the below way.

```
<form class = 'form-class'
  #thisFormName = "ngForm"
  (ngSubmit) = "saveData(thisFormName.value)"
>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'firstName' placeholder="Enter First Name ..." ngModel>
  <input type = 'text' name = 'lastName' placeholder="Enter Last Name ..." ngModel>
  <span>{{ selectedLang }}</span>
  <ul >
    <li *ngFor = "let lang of languagesList" (click)="selectedLang = lang" > {{ lang }} </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Is there a way to add ngModel (or something similar) to `ul li` so that the controller gets the `selectedLang` when the user sumbits the form?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should not use `ul-li`to make a dropdown. It is intended to present data not to be used as a form control. You shoud use a `select`

Comment: Thanks @ADreNaLiNe-DJ , You are right, Select will solve my problem. I was wondering if you could do the same with ul li tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a dropdown, you should not use ul li.

In my mind, the best way is to use select with ngModel.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLang ">
  <option *ngFor="let lang  of languagesList" [ngValue]="lang ">{{lang }}</option>
</select>
```

If you want to use more detail in your dropdown, you can see these following components:

- [Primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown)
- [Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)
- [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Select will solve my problem. I was wondering if you could do the same with ul li tags

Comment: So it's fine :). Don't hesitate to mark your question like resolved

Comment: On the internals Primeng, Bootstrap, Material they are not using <select>